# Address bar in Safari gone!

Tags: safari

The address bar in my safari broswer has disappeared... I have quit my safari browser and reopened it, but the problem persists. This is what it looks like [image: My Safari] I have no idea why this is happening, but i use safari as my main browser so it has all my bookmarks, etc so i can't really just stop using it. Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Right click in the empty area > "Customize Toolbar" > drag the address bar back up.

You probably accidentally command-dragged it out.

Comment: @luca590 if this answered your question, click the "checkmark" icon by my answer to mark it as correct. :)

Comment: oh yeah sorry about that, i had clicked it but then it told me to wait for a minuet so i went to do something else and must have forgot about it :p. my bad

Comment: I did this on a computer and it didn't stick until the computer was ALSO rebooted. You may even have to run maintenance scripts/clear caches etc.

Answer (score 9):

With the introduction of Safari 6.0, the command key sequence changed for this from <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> +  <kbd>|</kbd>  to <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.

It's also the first item under the view menu, 'Show Toolbar' or 'Hide Toolbar.'

edit: in Safari 7.0 and OS X 10.9, this feature is still available through View > Hide Toolbar or View > Show Toolbar, however there is no command key sequence.